# C++ serialization caused segment fault

Tags: c++, serialization

I am building [a compressor based on Huffman](https://github.com/izgzhen/DSLib/tree/master/examples/Huffman), I used serialization of a `Decoder` to store the information needed to uncompress the file into a binary file named `decoder.bin`

**In `main.cpp`, it goes well**:

```
#include "Huffman.hpp"

size_t hash(CodeType cd){
    return cd;
}


int main() {
    /* ------- BUILD -------- */
    .....

    /* ------- ENCODE -------- */
    .....

    /* ------- DECODE -------- */

    Decoder dec(huffmanTree, root);
    std::ofstream ofs("decoder.bin", std::ios::binary);
    ofs.write ((char*)&dec, sizeof(Decoder));
    ofs.close();

    Decoder newDec;
    std::ifstream ifs("decoder.bin", std::ios::binary);
    ifs.read ((char*)&  newDec, sizeof(Decoder));
    ifs.close();

    std::cout << newDec.tree.getCap();
    newDec.restore();
    newDec.decode("encoded.huf", "decoded.txt");
}
```

But if I used a separated **`decode.cpp`** to implement the decoding process independently from `main.cpp`, which does encoding work, weird thing happens on my machine.

```
>  make -f makeDecoder 
clang++ -c --std=c++11 decode.cpp -o bin/decode.o
clang++ bin/decode.o bin/HTree.o bin/Huffman.o bin/bitsMap.o -o decode
>  ./decode 
1000Restoring ...
Segmentation fault: 11
```

All the code of `decode.cpp`:

```
#include "Huffman.hpp"

int main() {
    Decoder newDec;
    std::ifstream ifs("decoder.bin", std::ios::binary);
    ifs.read ((char*)&  newDec, sizeof(Decoder));
    ifs.close();

    std::cout << newDec.tree.getCap();
    newDec.restore();
    newDec.decode("encoded.huf", "decoded.txt");
}
```

(The 1000 is the printing of capacity, just ignore it)

So this is very strange that the same code behaved differently, and I can't figure out why `segment fault` would happen.

> If you are too busy to download my library from github and build this program, you may ignore this problem, thank you as well. But it would be of great help to me if you can :)

My machine info:

```
Apple LLVM version 6.0 (clang-600.0.54) (based on LLVM 3.5svn) 
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin14.0.0
Thread model: posix
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have two main functions. You have one in decoder.cpp and main.cpp, and it appears you are building main in your decoder make file.